# How can I get start and end of a week using dateFNS depeogn on the current date and custom start day?

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I want to get the custom start and end day of week from current date. For example

If current date is 10/01/2022 and my start of the week start form Wednesday then I want to get a week range between 29/12/2021 to 04/01/2022. Till now I have Monday as start of the week and Sunday as the end of the week. For that I am using below code to get the week range. How Can I get the custom week range?

```js
const date = new Date();
const start = dateFNS.sub(dateFNS.startOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 1 }), { days: 7 });
const end = dateFNS.sub(dateFNS.endOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 1 }), { days: 7 });
```

Comment: `weekStartsOn: 3` does the job (i.e. starts the week on Wednesday).